# Magento API Product info for a particular Store view?

Tags: python, magento

I am using [python-magento API](https://github.com/bernieke/python-magento) for fetching all the information of the product. It's working fine. It returns the values for the default store view.

```
>>> magento = MagentoAPI("xx.com", "80", "xx", "xxx", "/api/xmlrpc")
>>> product_info = magento.catalog_product.info(1234)
```

product_info gives me a `dict` for the default(English) view. I have 19 stores in my websites. How can I get the `product_info` for a particular store view say `store_id=11`?

```
>>> product_1234 = magento.catalog_product.list({"product_id":1234})
```

This works. But same `dict` filter `{"store_id":11}` doesn't work in `catalog_product_info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can pass an optional parameter of `store_id` to fetch the details of that store.

```
>>> product_info = magento.catalog_product.info(1234, store_id)
```